# React Native shadow in UWP

Tags: react-native, uwp

I have recently been experimenting with react-native for UWP and I want to ask if there is any shadow support for UWP yet.

Right now, I have this code for the container

```
const styles = {
  viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 12,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    elevation: 4,
    position: 'relative'
  }
};
```

but no shadow appears at the bottom like it does for android.

Comment: I have no experience on UWP but maybe react-native-svg work for you

Comment: @ShubhamSahu in react-native? I'm confused

Comment: oops! wait let me check...

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ask if there is any shadow support for UWP yet

No, no work has been started for UWP on this yet. In the [issue 953](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/953) @leonskim mentioned that :

> Shadow props(shadowOffset for an example) work on iOS, and Android has elevation to draw shadow under a view component. Any updates on adding shadow to the view component for Windows? It would be very helpful.

This issue addresses the WPF side implemented the shadow with [pull request 998](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/pull/998), but since UWP will have the different way that still not implemented.

You could  open a new issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues) to request the UWP side shadow feature.